# How to add two arrays into one array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to add a couple of arrays into one array in Javascript. It seems my way is not good enough. Let's suppose we have these three arrays as below:

```
var array_1 = [{"a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3}];
var array_2 = [{"d" : 4, "e" : 5, "f" : 6}];
var array_3 = new Array();
```

I would like to add array_1 and then array_2 into array_3. For instance, I want to make sure that array_1 is fully added first and then array_2 as below:

```
{"a" : 1, "b" = 2, "c" = 3"}
{"d" : 4, "e" = 5, "f" = 6"}
```

Could anyone please help me with this piece of code. Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `array_3.push(array1)` - push `array2` after?

Comment: See `Array.prototype.concat`

Comment: Is there any special reason why your arrays have just one element?

Comment: Do you need an array with 2 objects or 1 object with "a" through "f" keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var array_3 = array_1.concat(array_2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that you have your arrays set up is very strange. What you have are 2 arrays with 1 element in them each, and that element is an `Object` with 3 properties. The output that you listed is actually invalid javascript or JSON syntax. But, I can get you close to what you want, I think...

```
var array_1 = [{"a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3}];
var array_2 = [{"d" : 4, "e" : 5, "f" : 6}];
var array_3 = new Array();

function merge_objects(obj1,obj2){
    var obj3 = {};
    for (var attrname in obj1) { obj3[attrname] = obj1[attrname]; }
    for (var attrname in obj2) { obj3[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
    return obj3;
}

array_3[0] = merge_objects(array_1[0], array_2[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) which combines two arrays (or more) into a new array. All you need is:

```
var array_3 = array_1.concat(array_2);
```